# Using JIRA with clearcase

Tags: version-control, clearcase, bug-tracking, jira

I'm using clearcase as version control and JIRA as bug-tracking tool. Currently ccase and JIRA is not integrated for issue tracking. I'd like to integrate JIRA with ccase but I am a bit skeptical about the plugin available which is not supported/developed by the JIRA vendor. I doubt it's stability and reliability. What's the best way to integrated JIRA with clearcase. How effectively I can track bugs? I am specifically asking this because in our development practice we won't created too many branches. Rather we backmerge and maintain the branches. It will be left only if we've too many modifications in the branch and become quite unmanageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never managed to make the [Jira-ClearCase plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JCC/JIRA+ClearCase+Plugin) work well, mainly because the polling mechanism (which queries the new versions through the `ClearCaseIndexService`) was:

- too slow to return result
- didn't scale well with *large* Vobs.

I ended up using a custom field for referencing the extended path of the element(s) concerned by a Jira ticket.

Comment: >> I ended up using a custom field for referencing the extended path of the element(s) concerned by a Jira ticket.

Can you elaborate your answer?